# How do I adjust the brightness of a 3 V bulb?

Tags: voltage, resistors

I need to adjust the brightness of a bulb for my GCSE Product Design project and I can't find an easy way of doing that.

I've researched and found potentiometers and resistors but it just seems to cut power to the bulb as soon as I adjust it less than full.

All resistors and potentiometers have been in the voltage and current range by checking the description of the components i was purchasing and compare them to the description of the bulbs that i am using. I'm using a simple series circuit and need the options to be very compact as in needs to fit in a 1cm x 1cm x 3cm space.

Comment: How did you select your potentiometers to be "in the voltage and current range"?

Comment: What is "less then full", in your case? Isn't achieving "less than full power" spent in you bulb exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, OP likely expects a linear relationship between control and apparent brightness and is disappointed that its not. Apparently, an on/off switch is unacceptable.

Comment: What does "less than full" even mean?

Comment: The symptoms you describe indicate that your pot is grossly too high in resistance value.

Comment: Calculate the resistance of the bulb and get yourself a potentiometer of between 3-5 times that value which can take the current and you should be done.

Comment: If you're going to try using a potentiometer, I suggest getting a resistor of, say, half the value of the pot you're proposing and trying it. Does it reduce the brightness half way? If yes, then all is good. If the bulb didn't light then try a smaller value resistor, if it was too bright then try a larger value resistor. When you've found a useful resistor value, find a pot of about twice same value.

Comment: Try a light dimmer before a transformer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic ways to control the brightness.

[image]

**Analog(ue):**

Something that will **continuously control and change the current through the bulb**. This could be just a variable resistor. In the circuit shown it is a BJT (transistor).

The variable resistor (VR1) is used as a potential divider and so the voltage at the base of the BJT can be altered between +V and 0V. R1 prevents too much current going into the base of the BJT when VR1 wiper connects to the +V rail. The transistor has current amplification so the variable resistor does not have to take the current through the bulb.

*Note* I've set the supply voltage slightly higher than 3V so full brightness can be obtained when VR1 is slightly below maximum. This also allows for the voltage drop across the transistor.

**Digital.**

The bulb is turned ON and OFF very rapidly so it doesn't flicker. The circuit (in this case a 555 timer) can be adjusted to vary the ON and OFF (mark/space ratio) time of the pulse. At 50-50 (equal ON,OFF times), mid setting of the variable resistor, the POWER is half the maximum. At 25-75 it is less ON than it is OFF so the bulb is dimmer. At 75-25 the bulb is more ON than OFF so it is brighter. The circuit doesn't produce a 100 -0 or a 0-100 setting but should get close enough to control a full range of brightness.

Q1 is used to switch the current through the bulb ON and OFF. D3 ensures the output from the 555 when it is LOW (it doesn't get to 0V) doesn't keep the transistor ON. R2 limits the current into the base of the BJT.

This type of circuit (PWM or pulse width modulation) is commonly used to control power to motors, transformers etc.

Comment: There's also using a variable resistor in series with the bulb as an option ;)

Comment: Thta's only an option for *very* low currents. Most potentiometers are rated for a very low wiper current.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this work only by use of common collector structure. using a npn transistor and connect base by potentiometer to positive and control output current of emitter.

Answer (score 0):

The abbreviated and simple answer is with a double pole switch with a resistor or a potentiometer. These have to be selected/sized with the right power rating. It sounds like you're burning up the pot.  Rheostats were typically higher wattage variable resistors.